# Does the first amendment protect children forced to receive a religious education?

Tags: united-states, first-amendment, parental-rights, freedom-of-religion

Many parents "force" their children to receive religious education. Does the children's U.S. First Amendment right to freedom of religion allow them to get the police to stop their parents from doing this sort of thing? Or do First Amendment rights not apply to minors?

Comment: Comments archived in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117474/discussion-on-question-by-smithey-does-the-first-amendment-protect-children-forc).

Comment: OP here. Honestly, surprised this question wasn't closed for showing very poor research effort on my part.

Comment: @Smithey the question you might really want answered is whether Amendment 1 protects a parental right to have a state not interfere with them forcing religious education on a child.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's less that the first amendment does not apply to minors and more that the first amendment does not apply to the parents' conduct. The first amendment to the U.S. constitution reads (emphasis added):

> **Congress** shall **make no law** respecting an establishment of religion, or
> prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of
> speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to
> assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

Thus the first amendment applies to the conduct of the federal government (and has its reach extended to state governments through [*Cantwell v. Connecticut*, 310 U.S. 296 (1940)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/310/296/)). The parents' conduct, while perhaps objectionable morally, does not violate the children's rights under the first amendment, as they are neither the state nor the federal government.

Comment: There may be legal remedies if the parent's conduct rises to the point of abusive OR if the child is sufficiently old enough, could apply for legal emancipation.   In general these are first amendment neutral (it's not that the end goal of the abuse is making you go to church/sunday school by blatant methods of child abuse in general that's illegal).   Physically putting a child in a car is not in and of itself child abuse (otherwise we should line up CPS agents at every child friendly venue in the country and arrest parents whose children are throwing fits cause they don't want to leave).

Comment: That's true, there may indeed be other ways which the parents' conduct could be legally objectionable (though it's difficult if not impossible to say without further details). I just wanted to answer the more narrow question posed on the applicability of the first amendment.

Comment: Note that this confusion (about who exactly the First Amendment restricts the conduct of) seems to be rather common among Americans. I regularly see people trying to argue that the First Amendment should protect them from being censored or banned in private forums online.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - They generally argue that it *should*, as you correctly said, not that it *does*. Some time back, people argued that the First Amendment *should* apply to states and municipal corporations (i.e. cities). It did not previously, but then it did.

Comment: @hszmv Those causes of action arise out of statutes, not the constitution.

Comment: @Acccumulation Federal law does provide a private right of action against anyone acting under color of usage to deprive someone of their constitutional rights, however.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn that's because people who "know their rights" don't actually know their rights.

Comment: @Acccumulation:  All statues must be compliant with the U.S. constitution at all levels of government (per 14th Amendment) so in order for  the parents to have custody of their children because of abusive treatment, the fact that it was to take the child to a religious institution does not matter, so long as the behavior is abusive.   It is one thing to beat a child unconcious to take them to conversion therapy.  It's another matter to physically put a child in a car to go to church, against the child's wishes to play video games all Sunday Morning.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - I'd wager your moderators have seen it even more regularly.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn are you sure you aren't the one who is confused? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruneyard_Shopping_Center_v._Robins

Comment: @Hasse1987 -- the Pruneyard decision is about the application of the **California** constitution, not the US constitution.

Comment: I believe the effect of the First Amendment could lead in the opposite direction. If a state were to pass a law protecting children from being forced by their parents to receive a religious education, that law could be challenged on the grounds that it violates the parents' right to the free exercise of religion. But I don't know how the courts would rule.

Comment: @PJB Of course, the point is it establishes that public forum doctrine can be extended to private entities. Which is why Trump cited it in the EO (obviously federal) against online censorship. A case reached the US supreme court just last year, Manhattan Community Access. So people arguing that the FA should protect their speech online, though not currently law, has enough merit to have survived motions to dismiss and be granted cert.

Comment: A more interesting question may be whether A1 protects a parental right to have a state not interfere with them forcing religious education on a child.